# using sessions in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I would like the data that i enter in a text box on pageA  to be accessable on pageB

eg: User enters their name in text box on page A

page B says Hello (info they entered in text box)

I heard this can be accomplished by using a session but i don't know how.

can someone please tell me how to setup a session and how to store data in it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Session["valueName"]=value;
```

or

```
Session.Add("valueName",Object);
```

And You can retrieve the value in label (for Example) By

```
/*if String value */     
Label1.Text=Session["valueName"].ToString();
```

or

```
Label1.Text=Session.item["valueName"].ToString();
```

And also You can remove the session by;

```
/*This will remove what session name by valueName.*/
 Session.Remove( "valueName"); 

/*All Session will be removed.*/ 
Session.Clear();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// Page A on Submit or some such
Session["Name"] = TextBoxA.Text;

// Page B on Page Load
LabelB.Text = Session["Name"];
```

Session is enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do something like JohnOpincar said, but you don't need to.

You can use cross page postbacks. In ASP.Net 2.0, cross-page post backs allow posting to a different web page, resulting in more intuitive, structured and maintainable code. In [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/xpgpostbk_asp2_dc08102006235543PM/xpgpostbk_asp2_dc.aspx?ArticleID=9e2b12e6-7842-419d-a3c9-df58f6aba523), you can explore the various options and settings for the cross page postback mechanism.

You can access the controls in the source page using this code in the target page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    TextBox txtStartDate = (TextBox) PreviousPage.FindControl("txtStartDate ");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use session to do this, but you can also use Cross Page Postbacks if you are ASP.NET 2.0 or greater

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx

```
if (Page.PreviousPage != null) {
    TextBox SourceTextBox = 
        (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1");
    if (SourceTextBox != null) {
        Label1.Text = SourceTextBox.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is even a simpler way. Use the query string :

In page A :

```
<form method="get" action="pageB.aspx">
    <input type="text" name="personName" />
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

In page B :

```
Hello <%= Request.QueryString["personName"] %> !
```