# How to restrict multiple login in same browser

Tags: asp.net

In my project, there are four logins: Admin, Teacher, Student and Parent, and four master pages respectively. In logintable, typeId is stored as 1-student,2-teacher,3-parent,4-admin.

During login, I am checking the type and according to typeId, I lead to corresponding master page.

My problem is that, when I login as Admin, it leads to admin master page.
When I take another tab and in login page, I am able to login as another user. I don't want to take multiple logins in same browser. How can I restrict this?

Eg: when I login as teacher, teacher master page is opened and take next tab and when I login as student, it should not to be allowed

My code for login

```
int Type = DALLogin.LoginGetType(Login1.UserName);
if (Type == 1)
{
Response.Redirect("Student.aspx");
}
else if (Type == 2)
{
Response.Redirect("Teacher.aspx");
}
else if (Type == 3)
{
Response.Redirect("Parent.aspx");
}

else if (Type == 4)
{
Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Use session to store user data. Refer this .. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898990/using-sessions-in-asp-net    or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403378/how-to-use-session-in-asp-net